# Is keystone js webapp is SEO friendly?

Tags: keystonejs

I am building new web app using keystone js with hbs template. Can google crawl my website?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes Google will be able to crawl your site.

Handlebars templates will be rendered on the server before being sent to the client.

You might want to set meta tags in your templates to help with SEO.

On the following web page, there is a section called **3.2. SEO AND SOCIAL OPTIMIZATION** which you might find helpful:
https://nodevision.com.au/blog/post/tutorial-blogging-with-nodejs-and-keystone-cms